# Pokémon Gold and Silver: What are the chances of a clone being shiny?

Tags: cheats, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I've been playing Pokémon Gold, and I'm going to do a test.
But before I do this test, I need to see if anyone's already done it and confirmed the results.
The test is, **how long would it take to get a shiny Cyndaquil, Tododile, Chikorita, Sudowoodo, Ho-oh, or Lugia using cloning if possible?**
These Pokémon are only available once in the ***entire freaking game***, and I want 'em shiny.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon#Generation_II):

> In Generation II, Shininess is determined by the IVs of a Pokémon. If a Pokémon's Speed, Defense, and Special IVs are all 10, and its Attack IV is 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14 or 15, it will be Shiny.

If you clone a Pokemon you will get a perfect duplicate of the starting Pokemon, including nickname, level, moveset, OT, ID and IVs. This means that you can't obtain a shiny clone from a non-shiny Pokemon.

So, the chances of a clone being shiny are **zero**.

However, unique (but NOT Legendary) Pokemon are like any other Pokemon.
In a wild encounter, the probability of a Pokémon's IVs lining up in any of the above manners is `1/8192`.

Also, you can still breed them with *Ditto* looking for a shiny.

> Breeding has different odds due to parents passing on IVs to their offspring. 
>   For example, if one breeds a Shiny Pokémon properly, the offspring may have as high as a `1/64` chance of being Shiny, depending on the species of Pokémon.

This works with a shiny Ditto as parent, too.

Comment: Dang.  So this means without breeding, which I can't figure out, I'll never get my **BRUTIFUL SHINY SUDOWOODO**?

Comment: @SuperDoom1 You can also soft-reset until Sudowoodo spawns shiny, but this works only if you haven't caught it yet.